# Can a snake feel if a Parselmouth is around?

Tags: harry-potter, parseltongue

When Harry and the Durselys visited the zoo in the first book, the snake was sleeping all the time and didn't even move when the glass was knocked at. But when Harry moved closer to the cell, it opened its eyes and winked at Harry even though Harry hadn't said a word.

> Harry moved in front of the tank and looked intently at the snake. He wouldn't have been surprised if it had died of boredom itself -- no company except stupid people drumming their fingers on the glass trying to disturb it all day long. It was worse than having a cupboard as a bedroom, where the only visitor was Aunt Petunia hammering on the door to wake you up; at least he got to visit the rest of the house.
>
> The snake suddenly opened its beady eyes. Slowly, very slowly, it raised its head until its eyes were on a level with Harry's.
>
> It winked.

Did the snake feel that a Parselmouth was around? Because how else would it have recognized Harry as a Parselmouth as it winked at Harry before he uttered a word.